# Can I calculate another phones position in a room, both running the same app?

Tags: android

What I want to do, is with my app be able to create groups with bluetooth. Then for the app to calculate the relative positions and directions of every other phone in the group.

I dont want to use GPS.
Is this possible? I read about calculating the bluetooth signal strength, but wouldn't that be different depending what phone sends it, and depending of reflections in the room?

The point for this is to create an interactive game where people can play in groups, best working if they sit in a circle :)

Comment: No, you can't. GPS accuracy is about 7.5 meters. WiFi and BlueTooth can't measure position/distance.

Comment: in all technicality, you COULD conceivably calculate distance with a decent signal strength based algorithm for Bluetooth, etc...  The problem then becomes the angular part, which cant really be deduced from Bluetooth of wifi.  There may be another way using a radar based audio ping methodology, but I haven't actually figured that one mathematically out yet.

Comment: you can do that if you can do ultra wave sound, I did this but not with a phone, with an FPGA board and TR RX for ultrawave sound. But with just a phone I don't think you can do that at the moment if you don't have some other device besides the phone.

Answer (score 3):

This is a quite interesting question. I made a little example. For my model i assume that there are no walls between the Phones and the Connection to a WIFI Acces Point.

IMHO I came to the conclousion that it is not possible, because as you can see in the attached picture there are 2 possible locations for the "Mobile 1" because we got only two strength valuies to meassure.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

[image]

- **BLUE LINES**: Strength of wifi signal (must be calibrated at beginning)
- **RED LINE**: Strength of Bluetooth signal between the phones (must be calibrated at beginning)

If you do only want to calculate it with a bluetooth signal, this is not possible, because the position could be 360 Degrees around the phone

Comment: My thought exactly. However if we assume an ad hoc network with at least 3 members, and let the members share the whole table of distances. So there is member A,B and C.

A knows its own distance to B and to C, it also knows their relative distance to each other. Isn't it possible to calculate then?

Thats why I asked about signal strength and reflections. Also WiFi could be used p2p as well, so not only would you know mobile 1s distance to the router, but also the possible position relative mobile 2 in p2p?

Comment: Oh, hmmmm with three people it could be possible after a bunch of calibrating, algorithming, just tak my approach and add a 3rd person and have a look on it.

Comment: @Svennisen - in an arbitrary room, how do you KNOW where the router is?  Distance, no matter how many given, does not give directionality.  With audio, you may be able to utilize the the gyro, and compass to understand what 3D angles the speakers and microphone are pointed, ping out a frequency that you know, and listen for response.  This is truly the idea of sonar, but attempting to utilize it through multiple bounces off multiple sources more like a radar to get 3D positions. May also be able to do more of a send, response audio wise to distinguish walls from phones, etc...